ESP32 OTA Firmware Update with ESP-IDF Framework Fails with 'Magic Bytes Do Not Match' Error ESPhome
I am new to ESPHome and working with an ESP32 device. I'm trying to upload OTA firmware (.bin files) using the ESP-IDF framework. My ESP32 and laptop are connected to the same network, and I'm sending update requests to ESPHome. However, I'm encountering an issue during the update process.

I have configured my ESP32 with the ESP-IDF framework in my yaml file.

My laptop sends an update request to the ESP32 device, but the process fails with the error "Magic bytes do not match!"

I attempted the update using both a Node.js script (through socket communication) and direct requests, but the same error occurred.

When using the Arduino framework, the file uploads successfully, showing progress in the ESPHome logs.

Tested the OTA process with the Arduino framework, which worked without issues.

Used different methods to send the update request (ESP-IDF and Node.js), but both resulted in the same error.

Verified that the ESP32 and laptop are on the same network.


Error:
Component esphome.ota set Warning flag: unspecified
[10:38:13][W][esphome.ota:130]: Magic bytes do not match! 0x50-0x4F-0x53-0x54-0x20
[10:38:13][E][component:164]: Component esphome.ota set Error flag: unspecified
[10:38:18][E][component:176]: Component esphome.ota cleared Error flag

Here’s my current yaml configuration:
esphome:
  name: living
  friendly_name: "living Pulse"

esp32:
  board: esp32dev
  framework:
    type: esp-idf

api:
  encryption:
    key: ${living_API_KEY}

ota:
  password: ${living_OTA_PASSWORD}
  platform: esphome

logger:
  level: WARN

wifi:
  ssid: ${living_wifi_ssid}
  password: ${living_wifi_password}
  power_save_mode: none
  ap:
    ssid: ${living_AP_ssid}
    password: ${living_AP_password}

captive_portal:

What could be causing this "Magic bytes do not match!" error when using the ESP-IDF framework for OTA updates? Is there a different approach or configuration needed when using ESP-IDF compared to the Arduino framework?
